# Set Unique Permissions to blog default and post page

Tags: permissions, blog, unique

I have SharePoint Blog. Basically I want to set Unique Permissions to `defalut.aspx` and `post.aspx` pages. How to set unique permissions for SharePoint Blog default page or post pages?

Comment: You can access the post.aspx page from the Posts Library. Default.aspx may have to be tackled using SPD.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here hence had to make few assumptions. Blog posts by default get saved in to a library called Posts and this has the posts.aspx you are referring to. Instead of managing permissions of pages it's better to manage permissions of the site and decide who can posts blogs and who can read it. Here is more information: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Configure-permissions-for-a-blog-19e7b51d-6034-4347-9a8f-cc746ef66402